# subscribing to cdk scroll strategy events

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-cdk

I am creating a service that generates cdk overlays. What I am trying to do is find a way to listen to cdk scroll strategy events. More specifically, I want to know when the cdk closes an overlay using the "close" scroll strategy. The end goal is to create an observable that consumers can use to determine whether the overlay is open or not (to apply css conditionally and what not).

After doing a little searching, it looks like overlayRef has a property _portalOutlet which has a property _isDisposed (https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.ts). That looks like what I'm looking for, but of course these are private properties not available to consumers.

I can't imagine that cdk overlay really doesn't have a public property for something like this and I'm really hoping someone points out my ignorance. I'm using angular 5 by the way.

Comment: Did you look at [CdkConnectedOverlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay) detach EventEmitter?

Comment: <ng-template #list cdkConnectedOverlay (detach)="onDetach()"> i tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work. The event never gets caught.

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

```
if (dropdownConfig.scrollStrategy === "close") {
  overlayRef.detachments().subscribe( _ => {
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.isOpenSubject.next(false);
  });
}
```

Hope this helps a random soul.